# Smooth CSS transition using media queries

Tags: html, css-transitions

I'm trying to create a smooth transition for a div that's placed elsewhere when `@media only screen and (max-width: #)` changes. The idea is when the max-width reaches, let's say, 600 pixels, the div smoothly transitions to another position.

Here's the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/8nQ6v/399/

This is a similar fiddle, transition is controlled by a click on the button:
http://jsfiddle.net/8nQ6v/2/

HTML

```
<div id="square" class="position">
```

CSS

```
#square {
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   background-color: red;
}

.position {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 20px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px){
    .position {
       position: static!important;
    }
}
```

With the current HTML & CSS it instantly hops to the other position. I'm wondering if there is someway to smoothly transition this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can use css transition to animate

```
transition: ease all .5s;
```

and to animate don't change the position try changing the values

```css
#square {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: ease all .5s;

}
.position {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 300px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .position {
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="square" class="position">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example how you can do this. you can use **translate: transform** to position the element in screen. Resize your window to see the difference and smooth effect.

```js
$(function() {

  $('#square').on('click', function() {

    $('#square').toggleClass('position');

  });

});
```

```css
#square {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: tomato;
  position: absolute;
}
.animate {
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out, left 1.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out, left 1.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out, left 1.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out, left 1.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out, left 1.5s ease-in-out;
}
.position {
  transform: translate(300px, 200px);
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .position {
    transform: translate(50px, 20px);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="square" class="animate">


</div>
```